# catch groovy JsonSlurper parseText exception

Tags: jenkins, groovy

```
groovy> def d = '{"a": 1, "b": {"bb": 2}}, "c": 3}' 
groovy> def m = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(d) 
groovy> println m 
groovy> println m instanceof Map 
 
[a:1, b:[bb:2]]
true
```

Obviously there is a redundant } at key b, but groovy can also parse, and key c lost. How to throw exception?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately it's a feature of groovy json slurper...

the only way i found as workaround - when you want to validate json without external json parser:

```
import groovy.json.*
def d = '{"a": 1, "b": {"bb": 2}}, "c": 3}'
def m = new JsonSlurper().parseText('['+d+']')[0] //parse as array and get first element
```

Comment: Unfortunately it will not cover all the error cases...